# Orbeon forms won't start with Tomcat XAMPP

Tags: tomcat, xampp, orbeon

I'm trying to install Orbeon forms with Tomcat via XAMPP. I follow the installation steps that are described here http://doc.orbeon.com/installation/tomcat.html, but when I enter http://localhost:8080/orbeon I get a 404 error. I tried to deploy the .war file via Manager App, but I'm getting the same 404 error. I also tried the PE version trial, and some of the old builds, all with the same result.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the CE version first or just the PE? If the PE you need license installed.

Comment: Both, and I installed the license, but it wasn't working anyway

Comment: First thing to do would be to check the Tomcat logs to see if there is any error. Second thing is to [setup Orbeon Forms logging](http://doc.orbeon.com/installation/#logging-configuration) so that you have an `orbeon.log` file and see if there is an error there.